# Windows event logs have null entries

Tags: logging, windows

I was looking through Windows event logs and found that there are a large amount of event logs with:
`[Type]="(null)" [User]="(null)" [Message]="null"` in the log.

For example, Event type 4740 should look something like this:

```
A user account was locked out.

Subject:

    Security ID:  SYSTEM
    Account Name:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y$
    Account Domain:  WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:  0x3e7

Account That Was Locked Out:

Security ID:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y\John
    Account Name:  John

Additional Information:
    Caller Computer Name: WIN-R9H529RIO4Y
```

In my case, all of this is null. What causes this to happen?

Comment: Was the event ID 4740? Also as sysprep used in in creation of the images used on the installation?

Comment: The event was also 4740. I am not aware of whether or not this tool was used.